# App crashes randomly on viewWillDisappear()

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, and I find some strange crashes in my app.

The Fabric reports said crashes occurred in viewWillDisappear().

I have two ViewControllers.User tap button in A viewcontroller then they move to B viewcontroller to input something, they user go back, and A get information from B.

I use a delegate to complete this task.

B:

```
class LessonNameTagTableViewController: UITableViewController {

...

var delegate:PassingData?

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    lessonName = (tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))?.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextField ).text!

    delegate?.changeLessonNameTag(name: lessonName, tag: tagColor)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

}
...
}
```

A:

```
class LessonEditTableViewController: UITableViewController,PassingData {
var lesson :Lesson?
...
func changeLessonNameTag(name:String,tag:UIColor){
    self.lesson!.lessonName = name
    self.lesson!.lessonTagColor = tag
    tableView.reloadData()

}
...
}
```

The crash happened randomly, I've tested it on my device, and nothing happened.But others said they could repeat this crashes.

I wonder whether I'm using delegate right or it's caused by other reasons.

Comment: Can you post your crash report?

Comment: There are three exclamation marks in that code: `as!`, `text!`, `lesson!`. Every one of them means "crash me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a problem in you viewWillDisappear, there's many optionals there that can cause you trouble when you force-unwrap.

It's better to be crash safe:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if let lessonName = (tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))?.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField)?.text {
        delegate?.changeLessonNameTag(name: lessonName, tag: tagColor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `IndexPath{0,0}` isn't visible when `viewWillDisappear` is called, then this line will set `lessonName = nil` as there is no cell for that row.  That will cause the following line to crash.

```
lessonName = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))?.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextField ).text!
```

As others have mentioned, there are too many forced unwrappings.

However, unless that cell was dynamically populate by the user, you should be able to get the same value from your `UITableViewDataSource` - so it will work if the cell is visible or not.

Additionally, don't force unwrap `lesson` in your delegate method - could be `nil`.

```
func changeLessonNameTag(name:String,tag:UIColor){
    self.lesson?.lessonName = name
    self.lesson?.lessonTagColor = tag
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My gut reaction is that one of the object's you're force unwrapping is in fact `nil`.

Instead of force unwrapping it using the `!`, you should safely unwrap it and fail gracefully if it is not present:

```
func changeLesson(name: String, tag: UIColor) {    //Updated formatting and method declaration to fit with current Swift standards
    guard let lesson = lesson else {    //Don't need to reference self here
        return
    }

    lesson.lessonName = name
    lesson.lessonTagColor = tag

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

See @orxelm's answer for how to safely unwrap your text value in B

Always be **very** wary when using the `!` operator. Even if you think you can guarantee that the object will not ever be nil.